# After snapshot boot : Informix Client -23101 / Oracle instant client -28759

Tags: php, linux, oracle, redhat, informix

Not to waste your time, I'll describe what I had && what I have now. My apps are written on php. They live on redhat6 server with nginx + apache web servers. We store data in MySQL DB, but we have lots of imports from Oracle and IBM Informix DB's, & mssql. For Oracle & Informix I have installed clients &&  compiled libraries pdo_oci.so & pdo_informix.so . For a few months they were working as expected.

But a week ago, admins made a snapshot of out virtual server, and reloaded it. Now only MySQL and mssql connectors work, and Oracle & IBM clients thows errors.

**Oracle : -28759**

```
Failed : SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-28759: failure to open file (/usr/local/src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_oci/oci_driver.c:579)/opt/project/www/test.php149
```

**IBM Informix : -23101**

```
Failed : SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -23101 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Unspecified System Error = -23101./opt/project/www/test.php146
```

Well, as official documentations says, Informix error is connected with the lost env variables of DB_LOACALE & CLIENT_LOCALE...etc.

[image]

This is strange, because all this time I was using this string for my connections :

```
     $dbh = new PDO ("informix:host=example.ru; database=some_db; server=db_net; CursorBehavior=0; DB_LOCALE=en_US.57372; CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.57372;", "db_login", "pass");
```

I tried to set up this env variables for apache (httpd) , but this error still accures. Now I have this variables set after server reboot, but no success. May be I'am doing something wrong or at the wrong place or user name...

About Oracle , documentation says that it is connected with files loading:

[image]

And the web doc says that it is mostly ssl error and is connected with the trouble of the client, that can not find SSL Wallet files. I Have TCPS secure connection to Oracle DB with wallet, and I remember that it was a real trouble to make Instant client to look at the right place. More than that, I have client tracing enabled, but it is writing log only when I use sqlplus directly from terminal. When I run my php scripts, I got only errors and no log.

Questions:

1. How to enable Informix variables correctly, or how to resolve this
   issue in different way.
2. How to enable "net tracing" for oracle, to
   see what he is looking for?
3. How to store this variables for future
   reboots/reloads/snapshots...etc. ?

Comment: still no comment... =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be related to file / dir permissions rather than env variables.
The oracle error seems to indicated that it can no longer open/read the files it requires.

The informix -23101 error can also be caused by the driver being unable to read GLS files required for locale support.

Does the apache user have access to the Informix Client SDK directories and files?

Comment: Well. To resolve this trouble I searched how to get most valuable information : what the system is doing. I found info about strace command.

Comment: I created a log using it and found a lot. Now my trouble with Oracle is resolved. Maybe not the best way but still. Problem was connected with the different confs for php for different users. root was searching wallet files as it was written in /root/.sqlnet.ora , but  php under apache user was searching for it in default path  etc/apache/….  Trouble was connected with reading sertificates files. Now Oracle connection is working. Informix is still not working.

Comment: The problem of Informix is not connected with user rights. If i call test under  /usr/local/src/php-5.3.3/sapi/cli/php, than test fails.

`sudo -u root strace -o /tmp/web_informix.log /usr/local/src/php-5.3.3/sapi/cli/php /opt/project/www/test_console.php`

But if  /usr/local/bin/php или /usr/bin/php,  the connection is successfull.

`strace -o /tmp/web_debug.log /usr/bin/php /opt/project/www/test_console.php`

In logs there is no errors till the end of the log. 
I can provide two files of successful and fail connection, if some one can help with them.

Comment: Checked logs for "gls" and found that success connect have strings like :

`open("/opt/IBM/informix/gls/lc11/en_us/e01c.lco", O_RDONLY) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=83981, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f8d878a1000
read(5, "FILE_TYPE=locale_object\nCOMPILER"..., 4096) = 4096`

And fail log :
`open("/usr/informix/gls/lc11/en_us/e01c.lco", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
`

Comment: The driver is searching the file "e01c.lco". In success case it searches in `/opt/IBM/informix/gls/lc11/en_us/e01c.lco` and it fails when it tries to search in `/usr/informix/gls/lc11/en_us/e01c.lco` . What is the actual installation directory for the GLS software?

Answer (score 1):

People. **Enable tracing of all what is possible** and use "**strace**" command to check where programm is failing!!!

**Thanks to Luís Marques!** I found gls in my logs and tried to make link for it.. to real IBM/informix/gls... than another msg trouble acured.../ I made soft link from /usr/informix to my real /opt/IBM/informix and **all connections successfully woke up!**

**Thank you man. You really helped me to finish this trouble. I post this as ansver but will accept yours as thanks to you! =)**

Comment: Glad i could be of some help. This is probably caused by the env variable `$INFORMIXDIR` being set to different locations. May be something in one of the configuration files of the web servers/php.

Comment: $INFORMIXDIR variable is set, and is poining to /opt/IBM/informix directory, but i suppose that apache cannot see it..

Comment: Same problem here. INFORMIXDIR env var is not being honored by the web server and it tries to find IFX files in the default location (i.e. /usr/informix).